# How to change a string array within a function

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with changing the values of an array of strings.
The point of the code is to check what story number it is, then change the values of the string array, then print it out in the choices function via the forloop.

```
void CheckDecisions(std::string choices[], int num_choices, int story_number)
{
    //choices = new std::string[];
    const int num = 4;
    num_choices = num;

    if (story_number == 0)
    {
        std::string start_choices[num] = { "", "Home", "The Store", "Your friend Taylor's place" };
        choices = start_choices;
    }

    if (story_number == 1)
    {
        //std::string_choices[num_choices] = { "", "Hummana", "Hummana", "Yes!" };
    }
}
```

It doesn't change the string's value and still returns empty. What is the correct syntax?

Here's the entire code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


void CheckStoryArk(int choice, std::string story, int story_number)
{
    if (story_number == 0)
    {

        if (story == "Home")
        {
            printf("story is Home\n");
        }

        if (story == "The Store")
        {
            printf("Story is Store\n");
        }

        if (story == "Your friend Taylor's place")
        {
            printf("Story is Taylor\n");
        }
    }



    if (story_number == 1)
    {
        if (story == "whatever")
        {
            printf("something");
        }
    }



    if (story_number == 2)
    {
        printf("story number is 3\n");
    }

    if (story_number == 3)
    {
        printf("story number is the end\n");
    }
}



void CheckDecisions(std::string choices[], int num_choices, int story_number)
{
    //choices = new std::string[];
    const int num = 4;
    num_choices = num;

    if (story_number == 0)
    {
        std::string start_choices[num] = { "", "Home", "The Store", "Your friend Taylor's place" };
        choices = start_choices;
    }

    if (story_number == 1)
    {
        //std::string_choices[num_choices] = { "", "Hummana", "Hummana", "Yes!"      };
    }
}




//Prints out choices
void Choices(int num_choices, std::string choices[], int choice, std::string story, int story_number)
{
    CheckDecisions(choices, num_choices, story_number);

    for (int i = 1; i < num_choices; i++)
    {
        //printf("%d %s\n", i, choices[i]);
        std::cout << i << " " << choices[i] << "\n";
    }

    std::cin >> choice;
    if(choice >= num_choices)
    {
        printf("That's not a valid answer, dickbag!\n");
        std::cin >> choice;
    }

    story = choices[choice];

    CheckStoryArk(choice, story, story_number);
}


void Story(int story_number, const int num_choices, std::string choices[], int choice)
{
    printf("You're driving down the streets of Los Angeles, where are you going?\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < story_number; i++)
    {
        Choices(num_choices, choices, choice, choices[choice], i);      
    }
}

void main()
{
    const int num_choices = 4;
    int story_number = 4;
    int choice = 0;
    std::string choices[num_choices] = {};

    Story(story_number, num_choices, choices, choice);
}
```

Comment: [Passing arguments by reference..](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not your syntax that's the issue, it's that you're invoking undefined behaviour.

```
std::string start_choices[num] = { "", "Home", "The Store", "Your friend Taylor's place" };
choices = start_choices;
```

When your function exists, the `start_choices` array will be destroyed, so assigning it to `choices` and trying to access it outwith the function is undefined.

Instead, copy the data into your `choices` array:

```
std::copy (std::begin(start_choices), std::end(start_choices), choices);
```

Or alternatively just use `std::vector` and avoid the headache completely.

Comment: It didn't work, it just spits this error out 

 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'

Comment: I ended up just doing this and it worked


  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
   choices[i] = start_choices[i];
  }